# Objects in same class, least resources situation

Tags: c#, object, parameters, resources

Hypothetically the following situation:

One creates an instance of an object in a method, this instance is used by another method from this same class.

Which takes the least resources from the machine?

```
class processor 
{ 
    private User user; 

    private void iDoSomethingWithUser(string name, int age) 
    { 
        user = new User();
        user.name = name;
        user.age = age
        setUserActive(); 
    }   


    private void setUserActive() 
    { 
        user.isActive = true; 
    }
}
```

or

```
class processor 
{ 
    private void iDoSomethingWithUser(string name, int age) 
    { 
        User user = new User();
        user.name = name;
        user.age = age
        setUserActive(user); 
    }   


    private void setUserActive(User user) 
    { 
        user.isActive = true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: If your app is running so slow that you think _this_ is the optimization you should take.  Something is _seriously_ wrong...

Comment: thank you very much for putting a new hypothetical situation to the one I have already created... in mine there is no such case as 'being slow' or whatsoever, I just want to know what the best practise is.

Comment: Best practice here would not be determined by speed, I doubt you'd measure a significant difference between each example you showed. Instead think about whether you want the object `User` to persist outside the lifetime of the method `iDoSomethingWithUser` as this is the major difference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first solution you declare `user` as global variable and it can be used in whole class while in second solution you declare it only for void and after void finish, that variable will be disposed.

Anyway there is not much benefits from doing either way since your application will not get much more resources if you use first solution but with second solution your code will be more organized and you will be able to use same var names in more voids:

```
class processor
{
    private User user;

    public processor()
    {
        user = new User();
    }

    private void UseSameVarName()
    {
        int user = 0; //it will not allow you to use `user` as another var name since you already have that name as `User` var
    }
}
```

And if you declare variables inside voids it will allow you to use same name

```
class processor
{
    private void CheckUser()
    {
        User user = new User();
        if(user.Name == ....)
        //other stuffs
    }

    private void GetUser()
    {
        int user = 0; //it will allow you to use user as variable name since you do not have it declared (you had it inside other void but it is declared only for that void)
    }
}
```

Also have in mind what you are doing when creating `User()` class. If you are doing some complex things that take time and you are using that class often not only in one void, it is better to declare and initialize it once than doing that every time.

Comment: The first part of your answer is right, but the second part seems to have gone off the rails...

Comment: If it's about code organizing then it's of course clear what the best practise is, I was wondering which would take less resources. Since there is no case of any difference whatsoever I have my answer.

Comment: About resources it is not big difference since you will struggle with much complex things that this will be nothing, but as i said, i do not want to repeat myself, read my last sentence and have that in mind.

Comment: Yes that last part already had my preferrence before I asked this question, and without any difference in resource usage I can continue on this.